# How are base learners ensembled in a gradient boosting machine

Tags: boosting

I'm trying to understand how gbm's work at their core. So far, I believe that they run a basic decision or regression tree in the first step. Then they would work off of the residuals in the first step to create additional trees according to some loss function. In practicality, I can draw out the first step (pictured below), but I want to know what the subsequent step would be after I've optimized my first tree according to Information Gain. Here, the only residuals would appear in the far right node where entropy is still 1.

Can someone explain what the next step would be and potentially more around how it iterates through a loss function?

I edited some data I found which is easy to work with and created a decision tree using info gain below.

EDIT: I have since found out how this works with continuous data but I'm still confused with categorical outcomes  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRktKszFmSk&list=LLkwQlvQktY6I-s5cp9sz4Ug&index=2

[image: data set]

[image: decision tree built from data set]